# Javascript date addition

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do computations on Javascript dates, and the following thing happens:

```
var date = new Date()
  undefined
date * 2
  2815580408292 
date - 10000
  1407790194146
date / 6 
  234631700691
date + 10000
  'Mon Aug 11 2014 13:50:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)10000'
```

It was going so well until I got to the +, where it turned from performing the operation on the milliseconds to concatenating strings. I need + to perform addition on milliseconds, not string concatenation. I'm doing this weird code-generation thing, so I can't do stuff like date.setTime(date.getTime() + 10000) without extraordinary effort and sullying the codebase. Is there some way of hacking Javascript so that + will add the milliseconds instead of concatenating as strings, or is there some date library that I can use + on its date objects and have it do addition rather than concatenation? I tried date.js but it concatenated too.

Comment: This is Javascript.  You're expecting all that to make sense?

Comment: Just throwing this out there since you asked for libraries. [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) might have the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: This was marked as duplicate a little bit quickly so I'll post the answer to your question as a comment. You can't change `+` behavior, it works as described here: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1. The key is that `ToPrimitive` on an object will basically try `toString` first and `valueOf` then. So if you really would like to hack `+` the only solution is to override `Date.prototype.toString`, _but this has far reaching consequences for all the JS code running on your page!_. My advice is to fix your code generator to output proper code.

Comment: I should add that the trick I was refering to in my previous comment is that you don't have to actually return a string from `toString`... This works: `Date.prototype.toString = function() { return this.getTime() }`. It "works" but also probably breaks a lot of code that assumes `toString` returns the string representation of your date... :(

Comment: That's exactly the kind of black magic I was looking for. Thanks jods, I'd accept your answer if it was one.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
date.getTime()+1000
```